# Another SQL user for python script?

Tags: python, mariadb, rfid

I'm following [this](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-rfid-attendance-system/) guide on building a RFID attendance system. I also like to know why I'm doing what I'm doing.
When it comes to building the SQL database, I need to create a user that i will use in a python script.

My question is: Why create another user? I mean, couldn't you just use the root user that was created when installing MariaDB?

Answer (score 0):

There are some subtle differences between `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES` and a `root` user that you can quickly see some simple notes [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/262046/difference-between-root-and-all-privileges).

But the short answer to your first question is: for more limited privileges. Now, whether that was the intention within the guide, I'm not sure.

Regarding your second question of whether or not you *could* just use the root user, sure, you could. But whether you *should*, really depends on the context/intention of your solution.